# How can I create and edit a list during recursion?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I need to create a function that would return two lists. The first one is a list of strings containing "found" and "dummy" indicating the element where numbers in two lists are identical.  The Second list contains a certain number of integers, the range is given by the parameter "colors" which returns the amount of times a certain number is found.  Currently I have accomplished the task of the first list, but the second list is confusing me quite a bit. In addition, you must use recursion in the process. Here is the code so far

```
def find(code, guess, colors):
    if guess == []:
        return []
    else:
        if guess[0] == code[0]:
            return ["found"] + find(code[1:], guess[1:], colors)
        else:
            return ["dummy"] + find(code[1:], guess[1:], colors)
```

A possible outcome would look like this:

```
>>> find([1,2,3],[3,2,1],6)
[[’dummy’, ’found’, ’dummy’], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Could you please explain why `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]` in terms of the arguments you give to `find`?

Comment: @jacobieski If you're happy playing recursion, I'd like to recommend you "The Little Schemer" by Friedman & Felleisen.  Not a Python book though.

Comment: Your code is clearly expected to return two lists, but all three `return` statements only return one list. So obviously you have to change the first one to something like `return [], []`. For the second, you're probably going to need to do it in two steps, like `a, b = find(code[1:], guess[1:], colors)` so you can do something like `return ["found"] + a, [1] + b`. (You _could_ do that in a single like by zipping and unzipping the two lists, but that just obfuscates your code for no good reason.)

Comment: (PS, that `[1]` in my expression above is completely arbitrary, since I have no idea what determines your second list, only that you're piling on some 0's and 1's according to some rule or other. You obviously need to code the actual rule that you haven't explained, rather than always prepending `1`…)

Comment: you get [0,0,1,0,0,0] you set the range of colors to 6, there for you should get a list of 6 zeros, from there you add one to a zero if you found that number, in this case there is a 2 in the list, so you add 1 to the element of 2

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for something like this:

```
def find(code, guess, colors):
    def sub(code, guess, lst1, lst2):
        if guess:
            if guess[0] == code[0]:
                lst2[code[0]] += 1
                return sub(code[1:], guess[1:], lst1+["found"], lst2)
            else:
                return sub(code[1:], guess[1:], lst1+["dummy"], lst2)
        else:
            return lst1, lst2
    return sub(code, guess, [], [0]*colors)
```

then

```
>>> print(find([1,2,3], [3,2,1], 6))
(['dummy', 'found', 'dummy'], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find(code, guess, colors):
    def wrapped_find(code, guess, color_list):
        if guess == []:
            return []
        else:
            if guess[0] == code[0]:
                color_list[code[0]]+=1
                return ["found"] + wrapped_find(code[1:], guess[1:], color_list)
            else:
                return ["dummy"] + wrapped_find(code[1:], guess[1:], color_list)

    color_list = [0]*colors
    #the color list will be transmitted and modified each time a match is found.
    match_list = wrapped_find(code, guess, color_list)

    return match_list, color_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(find([1,2,3,4],[3,2,1,4], 6))
```

Result is :

```
(['dummy', 'found', 'dummy', 'found'], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```